# How to identitfy my javascript execution engine

Tags: javascript

How can I see what javascript engine I am using, like mozilla Rhino / Spearmonkey???

Comment: where and when do you expect the results?

Comment: you can use some [UA sniffing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_user_agent_string_reference) ... but it's not very recommended... maybe [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) can help you.

Comment: Please provide the need as well as the effort that you put into finding the answer to this specific question in here.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines) list should give the answer

Comment: Do you just mean you want to know what JavaSscript engine your browser uses, or are you asking for a way to have your javascript code identify the engine under which it's running?

Comment: just want to know what JavaSscript engine my browser using to execute??

Comment: Like Chrome using V8 engine (I got this information by surfing the net). I would like to know, is there any other way to directly check the browser itself for its javascript engine.